# How to change image on button with @IBAction function and an observer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibaction

I have a button for audio player with function Play/Pause.

```
@IBAction func playPauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let playBtn = sender
           if buttonState == 1 {
               audioPlayer.play()
               buttonState = 2
               playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"),for:UIControl.State.init())
           } else {
               audioPlayer.pause()
               buttonState = 1
               playBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"),for:UIControl.State.init())
           }
}
```

and observer in didLoad for AVPlayer:

```
audioPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
```

How to change image for button in OBSERVE FUNCTION:

```
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "rate" {
            if audioPlayer.rate > 0.0 {
                print("audio started")
// change button image in "pause"
            } else {
                print("audio paused")
// change button image in "play"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using a storyboard, so add an outlet to the button (separate to the action outlet it triggers that you already have). You can reference the button using this from anywhere in that view controller, including in the observable function.

Comment: Thanks Chris for response, I'll try. I'm a beginner in swift and xCode.

Comment: You can drag an IBOutlet to reference the button in the same way you dragged across to make the IBAction. This lets you reference the button in code, rather than just call a function when it is tapped.

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot!!! You helped me a lot ... so simple was the solution ... as much as I feel so stupid... I hope this topic will help those who are stuck in simple and obvious tasks.

Comment: I’m glad this helped. I will add it as an answer so you can mark it solved, as it may help someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the button by adding an `IBOutlet`. You create this by ctrl-dragging from the storyboard to the view controller code, in the same way you did for the `IBAction`.

An `IBOutlet` provides a variable to reference the button (or other storyboard view). An `IBAction` triggers a function when the view is interacted with.

Example:

```
@IBOutlet var yourButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func playPauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) { }
```

Then later in your code you can refer to the button like this, which changes the image to a `UIImage` of your choice.

```
yourButton.setImage(image: yourImage, for state: .normal)
```